# Rotate a vector by radians whilst preserving magnitude

Tags: c#, math, vector, 2d

In this particular minigame, I need to be able to rotate a car left or right whilst still maintaining speed in whichever direction it's facing. This is the chunk of code i'm having trouble with:

```
private void turn(float angleDelta)
    {
        double r = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(carPosition.X, 2) + Math.Pow(carPosition.Y, 2));
        double theta = Math.Atan2(carPosition.Y, carPosition.X);

        carPosition = new Vector2((float)(r * Math.Cos(theta)), (float)(r * Math.Sin(theta)));


    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Update(gameTime);
        float angularVelocity = MathHelper.ToRadians(3);
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        {
            turn(-angularVelocity);
        }
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            turn(angularVelocity);
        }
        carPosition += carVelocity;
    }
```

Specifically in the turn(float angleDelta) method, I feel like i've entered the code properly, but i'm not sure where angleDelta would fit into this. I tried adding angleDelta to carPosition but that just gives errors.

Comment: Lets go back to physics.  Angular velocity can best be described as putting a ball at the end of a string and spinning the string.  If the ball spins around the circle once a second the angular velocity is 1 second/ 360 degrees.   If you are turning 90 degrees then the time for the turn is .25 seconds.  If you turn for a 1/2 second the your angle is 180 degrees.

Comment: My main problem here is how does the turn method not turn the car 3 radians?

Comment: 2 pi (radians) is 360 degrees.  So you want to turn car 172 degrees.  This line does not make any sense : float angularVelocity = MathHelper.ToRadians(3);  Radians is an angle, not a velocity.  It only makes sense if you are assuming the trun is being performed in 1 second.  Then you can say the angular velocity is 3 radians per second.  When you change the car position you will change 3 items : 1) x position 2) y position 3) angle of car.

Comment: Suppose you had a car facing North (Y positive axis) at position 1,0 (x,y).  Your angular velocity was 360 degrees/per second.  Now you moved for 1/4 second.  Your car would be at 0,1 and would be facing West (X negative axis)  I assume the radius (length of string) is 1.

Comment: So assuming  the turn is being performed in 1 second, how exactly do I code that? I tried adding: angleDelta += carPosition.X;
angleDelta += carPosition.Y;
angleDelta += carAngle;

Comment: However that code didn't do anything, the car just goes in a straight line and is unable to move left or right.

Comment: You need the radius and center of circle. Draw a coordinate axis.  Center of circle is at 0,0 with radius of 1.  if the car is at 1,0 and moves 90 degrees it is now at 0,1.  This assumes the car is not spinning and keeping the same orientation to the center of the circle.  So this is just a vector turning 90 degree to get location.  If the car is facing north initially it direction is 90 degrees from the location vector and will still be 90 degrees from the vector when it moves to 1,0.

Comment: What do I do once I have the radius and center of the circle? I don't know exactly how to 'add' the radians in code.

Comment: Radians is the angle the vector rotates.  In my case 1,0 (0 degrees) to 0,1 (90 degrees).  So once you get the new angle the x = redius * arcCos(angle), y = radius * arcSin(angle).

Comment: @jdweng you mean cos not arccos and sin not arcsin. That said, you are giving the equations to convert from polar to Cartesian coordinates which isn't the same as performing a rotation.

Answer (score 0):

It's a well-known matrix transformation in 2D:

```
u' = A*u
```

where

```
u = (ux, uy) as a column vector
u' = (ux', uy') as a column vector
A = | cos(theta) -sin(theta) |
    | sin(theta)  cos(theta) |
```

Velocity is a first order tensor, a vector which has both magnitude and direction.

This is an easy problem if you understand vectors and how to transform them.

Here's how I might code it in Java.  You should be able to easily convert it to C#.  As you can see, 2D planar rotation is a unitary process - magnitude is preserved, as you wish.

```
/**
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 2/23/2019.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54841329/rotate-a-vector-by-radians-whilst-preserving-magnitude/54843395#54843395
 */
public class VectorDemo {

    public static final int VECTOR_2D_SIZE = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double [] u = { 4.0, 0.0 };
        double umag = magnitude(u);
        System.out.println(print(u));
        System.out.println(String.format("u magnitude: %10.4f", umag));
        double angle = Math.toRadians(45.0);
        double [] v = rotate2D(u, angle);
        double vmag = magnitude(v);
        System.out.println(print(v));
        System.out.println(String.format("v magnitude: %10.4f", vmag));
    }

    public static double magnitude(double [] u) {
        if (u == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Vector u cannot be null");
        double magnitude = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < u.length; ++i) {
            magnitude += u[i]*u[i];
        }
        return Math.sqrt(magnitude);
    }

    public static double [] rotate2D(double [] u, double angleRadians) {
        if (u == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Vector u cannot be null");
        if (u.length != VECTOR_2D_SIZE) throw new IllegalArgumentException("2D vectors only");
        double [] v = new double[VECTOR_2D_SIZE];
        double [][] a = new double[VECTOR_2D_SIZE][VECTOR_2D_SIZE];
        a[0][0] = +Math.cos(angleRadians);
        a[0][1] = -Math.sin(angleRadians);
        a[1][0] = +Math.sin(angleRadians);
        a[1][1] = +Math.cos(angleRadians);
        for (int i = 0; i < VECTOR_2D_SIZE; ++i) {
            v[i] = 0.0;
            for (int j = 0; j < VECTOR_2D_SIZE; ++j) {
                v[i] += a[i][j]*u[j];
            }
        }
        return v;
    }

    public static String print(double [] v) {
        return String.format("(%10.4f, %10.4f)", v[0], v[1]);
    }
}
```

Here's my output:

```
(    4.0000,     0.0000)
u magnitude:     4.0000
(    2.8284,     2.8284)
v magnitude:     4.0000
```

Comment: See above.  I added Java code that works.  Should be easy to port to C#.